# How to iterate through a jquery dataTable using version 1.10.5 APIs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following code which was working fine with jquery dataTable 1.9.4, but not working in jquery dataTable 1.10.5, the first line inside the FOR loop doesn't work, it doesn't put a check on each row checkbox when the checkAll checkbox is checked.  Can someone let me know how to convert the code inside the FOR loop using 1.10.5 APIs?  I tried to use the following code, but not sure how to refer to each row within the function.  Many Thanks.

Use dataTable 1.10.5:

```
var dTable = $('#users').DataTable();
dTable.data().each( function() 
{
   // not sure what to do here
})
```

The following code uses 1.9.4 APIs which worked, but stopped working when I included 1.10.5 dataTable libraries:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"     src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>     

function checkAll() 
{ 
  var oTable = $('#users').dataTable();        
  var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();                     
  for(var i = 0; i < oSettings.aiDisplay.length; i++)
  {
     // doesn't work in 1.10.5,  put a check on the checkbox for each row
     $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes(oSettings.aiDisplay[i])).attr('checked', this.checked);        

     if ( this.checked == true )
     {
         $(oTable.fnGetNodes(oSettings.aiDisplay[i])).addClass('row_selected');
     } 
     else 
     {              
        $(oTable.fnGetNodes(oSettings.aiDisplay[i])).removeClass('row_selected');
     }
  } 
}
```

Datatable HTML:

```
<DIV id ="tablePanel">
   <table class="userTable" cellpadding="4" rules="all" border="1" id="users">      
  <THEAD>                                                                 
     <TR>                                    
       <th><input type="checkbox" id ="check_all"  class="call-checkbox" name="check_all" onclick="javascript:checkAll();">Select  users</th>
       <th>User Id</th>
       <th>Full Name</th> 
     </TR>
  </THEAD>
  <TBODY>
  </TBODY>                                      
  </table>   
  </DIV>
```

Comment: Your HTML has two opening `<tbody>` tags and no closing tag. It's also really messy. Try HTML Tidy for starters, you'll save yourself a lot grief by eliminating the sloppy errors. http://infohound.net/tidy/

Comment: yeah, that was a typo when I copied and pasted.

Comment: Do you want the checkbox checked for all items on all pages of data, or just the visible items?

Comment: just all items on all pages, so when "check all" is checked, rows on other pages should be checked too.   Thanks.